# Empty .HTML() on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to generate a divs inside my row. I am getting the data from my PHP using an JSON Array.

The problem is the columns are not displaying.

Here is my PHP code:

```
 $response[] = array(
    'CLIENTDETAILS' => $clientdetails,
    'SPOUSEDETAILS' => $spousedetails,
    'COMAKER1DETAILS' => $comaker1details,
    'COMAKER2DETAILS' => $comaker2details
);

echo json_encode($response);
```

Here is my Javascript Code:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: 'generate-application-approval-client-details.php',
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'TEXT',
    data: {applno : applno, clientid : clientid},
    success: function(response) {
        $("#display-client-details").html(response[0].CLIENTDETAILS);
    }
 });
```

Here is the Result of my JSON:

```
CLIENTDETAILS: "<div class="col-lg-4">
↵                <label>Client ID</label>
↵                <label class="form-control">2000013652</label>
↵            </div>"
```

I also tried yung .innerHtml but the result is Undefined.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: You're telling jQuery to expect plain text as a response, but then sending JSON from the server. Set `dataType: 'JSON'` to make jQuery to parse the response for you, or parse it manually in `success` function before using it.

Comment: A `<label>` should either wrap its associated `<input />` element or reference it via `for="<id of the input element>"`

Comment: @Teemu that's exactly it I forgot to change the datatype

Comment: Exactly you are sending JSON from PHP. You need to parse it in JavaScript. Add response = JSON.parse(response) in your success function.

Answer (score 2):

Yo have to parse your response in AJAX,

`let responseData = JSON.parse(response);`

**Your AJAX code should be like:**

```js
$.ajax({
   url: 'generate-application-approval-client-details.php',
   method: 'POST',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {applno : applno, clientid : clientid},
   success: function(response) {
       let responseData = JSON.parse(response);
       $("#display-client-details").html(responseData.CLIENTDETAILS);
   }
});
```